# How do you send a cross origin request from localhost?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have my front end running on localhost:8080 and my server on localhost:3000. I'd like to send a request from my front end to the server. When I do, I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/create-sharable-url' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I am using the http protocol, so why would I get this error?

<s>I'm trying to make the request from the `localhost` protocol, so that error makes me think that it just isn't possible to do. But on the other hand, sending a request from your client to your server in development mode seems like an incredibly common requirement.</s>

Googling around seems to point me in the direction of getting the CORS headers set on the response. I already am setting the headers on my server (using the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) npm package), but I figured I'd give it a go anyway. It didn't work for me though. The [Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) Chrome extension didn't work, nor did running Chrome with the disable web security flag.

**Client JS**

```
createSharableEquityCalculatorURL: function (storeState) {
  let data = this._constructEquityCalculatorData(storeState);

  return Vue.axios.post(`${process.env.BASE_API_URL}/create-sharable-url`, data);
},
```

Comment: @ADyson Ah, right. So then it looks like the protocol is http. If so, why would I get the error message? Http is listed as one of the protocol schemes that are supported in the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact it says "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/create-sharable-url " makes me think that in your JS you forgot to put `http://` at the start of the target URL.

Write it out in full in your code i.e. `http://localhost:3000/create-sharable-url`

Comment: I spent 3 hours searching the web, nothing worked, and this was the answer